# Compile entire C# project at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am trying to compile an entire C# project (Project A) within another C# project (Project B) and trying to generate it in memory, as much as possible.

I am loading all of Project A's source and references to its DLLs (which I am unaware of at compile time) into memory.
I will also have an unknown number of files that will either be added or updated in Project A, including any additional DLLs that will also need to be added or updated.

The DLLs are stored in a temporary folder, for now, and are in a `List<string>` with their fully qualified paths.

Then I try to compile Project A's entire source like so:

```
CompilerParameters compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters();
compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
compilerParameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(assemblyLocationsList);
CompilerResults compilerResults = new CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameters, rawSources);
```

where `assemblyLocationsList` is the `List` of the DLLs' locations and `rawSources` is a `string[]` of Project A's raw source code.

The issue I have is that `compilerResults.Errors.HasErrors` returns `false`, however, when I try to get the result of `compilerResults.CompiledAssembly`, I am faced with a `FileNotFoundException` and it appears to be "missing" the "EntityFramework.dll". I have checked and ensured that the DLL exists in the path specified and Project B has access to the file, which it does.

I may be misunderstanding how the `CompileAssemblyFromSource` is resolving the `compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies` (the fully qualified paths that I have specified) and if what I am trying to do is even achievable.

Does Project B need to `Assembly.Load` the assemblies for it to be able to "recognise" Project A's DLLs and then be able to use them in `compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies`?

I would also like to know if it's possible to keep the assemblies in memory (perhaps as a `List` or similar) and then use a "location" (when loaded in memory using `Assembly.Load` `Assembly.Location` is empty) when referencing them in `compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies` or am I stuck with just having to write them to disk and reading them from the temporary location or is there an alternative/better way to go about this?

I am trying to compile the code so I can eventually use `Reflection` to play with the code internally, that is, read the headers, attributes, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make a MCVE example? There is just not enough code to try this ourselves.

Comment: System.CodeDom does have its limitations, it is not much of a substitute for msbuild.  The GenerateInMemory options is but a parlor trick, all it does is call Assembly.Load(byte[]) for you.  The exact opposite of what you want, assemblies loaded that way have no loading context.  It is entirely up to you to ensure that dependent assemblies can be found by the CLR.  Use Fuslogvw.exe to find out where it is looking.